# Mathematical notation to describe tiling shapes?

Tags: notation, polygons, tessellations

I stumbled across the following Wikipedia article which contained information on [tiling by regular polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_by_regular_polygons).

Underneath each image, it contained a sort of sequence of numbers which appears to be representing the tiling pattern in some manner.

For example, a rhombitrihexagonal tiling (below) had a numerical sequence of "3.4.6.4"

[image: rhombitrihexagonal tiling]

What is the name of this notation called, and where can I find more information about it? Can it be used to determine how to tessellate any pattern without requiring further information? What about patterns that don't use regular polygons? And if not, does there exist some form of mathematical notation that can unambiguously describe any sort of tessellation?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [Wythoff symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wythoff_symbol), these are the vertex configurations. As for tiling notations, you can use the ones here, [(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_planar_symmetry_groups#Wallpaper_groups) these, [(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_symbol) or [(3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram) under various conditions. I couldn't tell you if orbifold notation works under conditions like Penrose tilings, but that would be the spirit of the thing.